# One adress (www.domain.com) for the whole website ? Do you recommend it for SEO?

Tags: php, apache, dns

Hello I'm planning to developp a communication platform fully in Ajax and Long-Polling.
There will be no full page reloading ! 
So the website adress would always be www.domain.com
Do you recommend that for SEO ?

Comment: Please try here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo

Comment: Well it really depends on what you want the search engines to discover

Comment: What pages you expect to be indexed by the search engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a [full specification](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) on how to make ajax-powered sites like this crawlable.

The trick is to update `window.location.hash` with an escaped fragment whenever you want specific content to be linkable, and treated as its own page, without having to reload. For example, Twitter rewrites their URIs from `http://twitter.com/user` to `http://twitter.com/#!/user`.

From an SEO standpoint these are both valid and will be regarded as its own separate page. They can be directly linked to, and be used in browser history navigation. If you update your meta-data (keywords, description etc.) and sitemaps accordingly, SEO will be the least of your worries.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, finally I don't need to use that trick since the only page which I want to be indexed by the search engines  is the welcome page.

Answer (score 7):

Forget about SEO, what about your visitors - will people be able to bookmark a page on your site and get back to where they want to be? Will they be be able to email a link to their friends to show them something?

Its not just Google that likes to have direct URLs to visit. Those direct URLs are vital for SEO, but they're also important for your human visitors too.

Comment: I totally agree although my website is a communication platform where people profile can't be accessed to all so there won't be anything to share.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can generate a fully qualified link for each page, you should be fine if you generate a sitemap including those links and submitting it to google.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on Twitter and FB, they #! in the URL so Google still crawls pages

Answer (score 1):

If it's mostly using Ajax for content population, loading and state changes, then it's probably a bad model for SEO purposes anyway. Somewhat of a moot point by nature, no?